# Picasso keeps using cached image

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I am using Picasso as follow to load images from my server:

```
String urlString = Constants.API.BASE_URL + "/storage/images/products/1.png";

Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
    .load(urlString)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_logo)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_products)
    .into(mIconImageView);
```

However, when I change the server's image at the same location as the loaded one:
`"/storage/images/products/1.png"`

Picasso still using the cached (old) image.

I have navigated away from my activity by preseing back then started it again. However, Picasso keep using cached image.

When I restart my application. Picasso updates its cache.

Is there away to let Picasso uses remote-first or cache-then-remote images?

Comment: try adding .skipMemoryCache() in picasso

Comment: try putting the Picasso code in onResume(). This way Picasso will load the image every time the activity is resumed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it first.

this may invalidate all memory cached images for the specified uri.

```
Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
            .invalidate(urlString);
```

call Picasso here again

```
Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
.load(urlString)
.error(R.drawable.ic_logo)
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_products)
.into(mIconImageView);
```

Comment: But I want the cache for offline use of my app :)

Comment: You must understand how caching works @malhobayyeb as long as your URL is same, Picasso or Glide will pick the cached image. Ideally you must save new images with new URL and update the URL in app.

Comment: @MohammedAtif If the image is update from my website? How can I handle such situation?

Comment: As mentioned @malhobayyeb , you can not have cache and update for the same url at the same time. You must either change the URL(image name) for every update or remove the cache as Dhiren mentioned in his solution.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I would like it to work like this: cache, remote if connected.

Comment: In that case, instead of caching, download the new image when connected and use downloaded image when offline. But even this is not reliable as you might end up downloading same image again and again.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I invalidated the cache on update from the phone

Comment: I have to change my solution to storing images on the server. I am using the product id on each time I store Image for that product. I have to generate random name for my image, I think.

Comment: Standard way of storing the images is "ImageActualName"+"time_stamp"+".jpg"; this wil always generate a unique name. So in your case you can have something like -> `MyProduct_ProductId_12354321.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
    .load(urlString)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_logo)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_products)
    .into(mIconImageView);
```